# Using dummy variable to determine state then change it with if / else

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure why I can't get this to work. I'm just a beginner though. Basically, I'm setting a variable and then change it based on the if / else condition. What I want to do is change the button_state to false after the button is clicked when it was set to true.

```
$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
var button_state = true;

if (button_state == true) {
//action
button_state = false; //change to false for the next time it is clicked, run the other statement
}

if (button_state == false) {
//action
button_state = true; //return to true
}
});
```

Comment: Always `true`...

Comment: @Tân, how can I modify the variable inside the if, so the next time it is clicked, the other statement runs

Comment: next time when you clicked on button this `var button_state = true;` will get executed which will return true put that part outside your `$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {..` and see

Comment: oh yeah, i just commented the answer, sorry for the trouble. but I got it too, now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the code to:

```js
var button_state = true;

$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
  button_state = !button_state;
  
  console.log(button_state);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="button">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to store the state of the button in a `data` attribute. This has the advantage that it will work for many buttons on the page, where using a single variable to store state will not.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
  if ($(this).data('state')) {
    //action
    $(this).data('state', false); //change to false for the next time it is clicked
    console.log("Button was true");
  } else {
    $(this).data('state', true); //return to true
    console.log("Button was false");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="button" data-state="true">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thanks, I knew I just forgot.. I made it work. I placed the variable outside the click event.

```
var button_state = true;

$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {

if (button_state == true) {
//action
button_state = false; //change to false for the next time it is clicked, run the other statement
}

if (button_state == false) {
//action
button_state = true; //return to true
}
});
```

Thanks! XD